# how to use achieve below requirement using spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am really new for Spark. would you please help below require..
I have below source file. first field is name, second field is group id. I need to count how many group the name has, and list all the groups and count.

```
abc 1
abc 2
abc 3
xyz 1
xyz 3
def 2
def 4
lmn 6
```

I want to get below ex

```
name    dept    count
abc    1,2,3       3
xyz    1,3         2
def    2,4         2
lmn    6           1
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a CSV file. So , first create dataframe using following steps.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.Row

    val members = sc.textFile("member").Map(lines => lines.split(",")).map(a => Row(a(0),a(1)))

val rddStruct = new StructType(Array(StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true),StructField("depart", StringType, nullable = true)))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(members,rddStruct)
```

To achieve the output, following steps can be followed.

Apply a groupBy function can collect all departments as a set

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("Name").agg(collect_set("Depart").as("Depart"))
df2.show
+---+-----------+                                                                 
| Name|   Depart|
+---+-----------+
|lmn|      [6]|
|def|   [2, 4]|
|abc|[1, 2, 3]|
|xyz|   [1, 2]|
+---+---------+
```

Then apply a size function on the Depart column to get the count.

```
val df3 = df2.withColumn("Count", size(df2("Depart")))
df3.show
+---+---------+-----+                                                           
| Name|   Depart|Count|
+---+---------+-----+
|lmn|      [6]|    1|
|def|   [2, 4]|    2|
|abc|[1, 2, 3]|    3|
|xyz|   [1, 2]|    2|
+---+---------+-----+
```

If result required should be sorted in descending order than you can apply a orderBy function on the above output.

```
val df4 = df3.orderBy(desc("Count"))
df4.show
+---+---------+-----+                                                           
| Name|   Depart|Count|
+---+---------+-----+
|abc|[1, 2, 3]|    3|
|def|   [2, 4]|    2|
|xyz|   [1, 2]|    2|
|lmn|      [6]|    1|
+---+---------+-----+
```

About structType you can read [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html)

Comment: Hi Rajat, thanks for your quick response. one more question. in your first step. groupBy("C1"), what the c1 mean? my source file doesn't have the field's name.

Comment: @kenHan Its the column name as actually for creating data just gave random column name.

Comment: Hi Rajat, my file doesn't have column name.

Comment: @kenHan After reading the data , you need to create dataframe providing a schema and from there it will get the column name

Comment: my sourcefile is csv file, so, first， I separate it with val members = sc.textFile("member").flatMap { lines => lines.split(", ") }

Comment: @kenHan updated the answer , this should clear your doubts

Comment: Sorry, Rajat, I am really new for Spark. maybe I start point is wrong.

Comment: @kenHan Still having doubts?

Comment: it is clear now. but I stuck in another issue. "object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark". I am not able to import  org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession package.

Comment: @kenHan stackoverflow doesn't work this way .Please ask another question for issue and accept this answer if its clear to you

Comment: Thanks Rajat for reminding me. this is second time I use stackoverflow. will close this one and open another one.

Comment: Hi Rajat, when I put  val df2 = df.groupBy("Name").agg(collect_set("Depart").as("Depart"))
I got below errors. would you please help this, thanks.
Multiple markers at this line
1. type mismatch; found: String("name") required: com.maven.spark.scala.Name1 =>?
2. not found: value collect_set
3. type mismatch: found: String("name") required: com.maven.spark.scala.Name1 =>?

Comment: @kenHan what you want to ask??

Comment: My code like below:package com.maven.spark.scala

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext


    case class Name1(Name: String, Dept : String)

object MultipleMember {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
    def conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MultipleMember").setMaster("local")
    def sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    
    val members = sc.textFile("member").map { lines => lines.split(",") }
    
    val df = members.map(x => Name1(x(0),x(1)))
    
    val df2 = df.groupBy("Name").agg(collect_set("Depart").as("Depart"))

Comment: Hi Rajad, the map operation: .map(a => .map(a => Row(a(0),a(1))) throw out error: illegal start of simple expression

Comment: @kenHan Sorry there was type .. i have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rajat. I hit another block: val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(members,rddStruct) give me error. "not found value sqlContext". I imported import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, it throw out another error: "createDataFrame is not member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext". I searched online. looks need to import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession. when I tried to import, it gave me error "SparkSession is not member of org.apache.spark.sql" would you please help this, thanks in advance

Comment: val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) . I guess you need to study the documentation properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple using RDD transformation:

```
scala> var rdd = sc.textFile("/data_test1")

scala> rdd.map(x => x.split(" ")).
 map(x => (x(0), x(1))).
 groupByKey().
 map(x => (x._1, x._2.toSet.mkString(","),x._2.size)).
 toDF("name", "dept", "count").show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+-----+
|name| dept|count|
+----+-----+-----+
| abc|1,2,3|    3|
| lmn|    6|    1|
| def|  2,4|    2|
| xyz|  1,3|    2|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks Rajat Mishra and KiranM